# Copying files using Terminal, Mac

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to copy files from one folder to another using terminal. I have a folder with thousands of files in it and I have a txt list with thousands of file names that match them. I need to copy only the files that are on the txt list to a new location.

I found this online and modified it for my disks but it is not working. Today is the first time I have ever opened Terminal so I don't know what I am doing of if this is even close to what I need. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

target="/Users/DataSourceSTL/Desktop/Photos"
destination="/Users/DataSourceSTL/Desktop/Test"

fnames=”/Users/DataSourceSTL/Desktop/Untitled.txt”

for info in $fnames; do
  cp ${target}/${info} ${destination}/
  exit 1
  echo "copying $info"
done

echo "done"
```

Comment: Make sure to use the correct double quotes. For `fnames` you seem to use the wrong ones. Which text editor are you using? TextEdit would be a good choice to start.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
for info in `cat $fnames`; do 
  cp -v "${target}/${info}" "${destination}/"
done 
echo "done"
```

Comment: You want to quote the arguments to `cp` in case any of the names have spaces in them.

Comment: @alesplin & Ken Thomases : true !

Comment: Note that the names in `$info` won't contain spaces; the shell will see to that.  The paths `$target` and `$destination` might in general contain spaces, although in the specific example here, those names are space-free.